# Excel VBA Auto Sort Once Row Has been completed

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code but I am getting the following error:
Run-time error '1004': 
Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

I can't seem to figure this out. The error appears on the If Not Intersect row. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("Table1[[#ALL],[Date]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
    :=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Time]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
    :=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Table1[[#All],[Associate]]")) Is Nothing Then
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").ListObjects("Table1").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

The above code works like a charm (human error). However once the code has finished it takes me back to the top of the table. Is there a way to keep the focus on the last row completed?

Comment: Works for me. Do you definitely have a column headed "Associate"?

Comment: I'd fully qualify the `Range("Table1[[#All],[Associate]]")`. Thisworkbook.sheets("Log")? I'd also suggest you use ThisWorkBook instead of ActiveWorkBook. ActiveWorkbook can cause unexpected errors if you swap to another workbook while the macro is running.

Comment: SJR - Yes I have a column header titled Associate.

Comment: Thanks Gravitate. After further review my column header had a space at the end of it. Once I removed it the code worked. I also made your recommendations regarding the ThisWorkBook. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The above code works like a charm (human error). However once the code has finished it takes me back to the top of the table. Is there a way to keep the focus on the last row completed?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the comments by SJR & Gravitate I rechecked my header column. It appears that there was an extra space at the end which once I removed it the code worked as intended.